# Error: Tuple index out of range while plotting learning curve

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tuples, logistic-regression

Here is my code:

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt,matplotlib.colors as clr

  import pandas as pd,csv,numpy as np
    from sklearn import linear_model

  from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit as ss, learning_curve as 
  lc,StratifiedKFold as skf

  from sklearn.utils import shuffle

  file=open('C:\\Users\\Anil Satya\\Desktop\\Internship_projects\\BD 
  Influenza\\BD_Influenza_revised_imputed.csv','r+')
  flu_data=pd.read_csv(file)

  flu_num=flu_data.ix[:,5:13]
  features=np.array(flu_num.ix[:,0:7])
  label=np.array(flu_num.ix[:,7])
  splt=skf(n_splits=2,shuffle=True,random_state=None)

  clf=linear_model.LogisticRegression()
  model=clf.fit(features,label)
  def classifier(clf,x,y):
    accuracy=clf.score(x,y)
    return accuracy

  lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=0.75,cv=splt,
  scoring=classifier(clf,features,label))
```

On execution, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Ankur/Python36/Python Files/BD_influenza_learningcurve.py", line 
26, in <module>

lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=0.75,cv=splt,
scoring=classifier(clf,features,label))
File "C:\Ankur\Python36\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 756, in 
learning_curve 
n_max_training_samples)

File "C:\Ankur\Python36\lib\site-
packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 808, in 
_translate_train_sizes

n_ticks = train_sizes_abs.shape[0]

IndexError: **tuple index out of range**
```

I am not able to identify the problem yet. But, I believe the problem is in the learning curve function because I have executed the program without it and it works fine.

Comment: Can you try this please?  ''import numpy'' as np and then ''lc(.......,train_sizes=np.array([0.75]) ,........)"

Comment: I made that change. But then it shows the following error:    score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Comment: Try this:''lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=0.75,cv=splt,
  scoring="accuracy")'' or "lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=np.array([0.75]),cv=splt,
  scoring="accuracy") "  Do you get any error?

Comment: Yeah! It finally works. I have the train_size,train_score and test_score outputs. Can you please tell me what was the issue before? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: the scoring parameter that you tried to pass seems that caused the error. I am going to post this as answer as you solved your problem and then you can accept it. Glad I could help

Comment: How does editing- scoring="accuracy" help? I mean this code does not access the variable accuracy.

Comment: For the scoring parameter you can see here the available attributes/strings that you can use: [see here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the scoring or train_sizes parameter causes the problem.

Try to replace:

```
lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=0.75,cv=splt,
   scoring=classifier(clf,features,label))
```

with

1)

```
lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=0.75,cv=splt,
   scoring="accuracy")
```

or 2)

```
import numpy as np

lc(estimator=clf,X=features,y=label,train_sizes=np.array([0.75]),cv=splt,
   scoring="accuracy")
```

Finally, for the scoring parameter you can see here the available attributes/strings that you can use: [The scoring parameter](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html)

Comment: I removed the code for function 'classifier' and the code was still working fine. How is it possible and what does " scoring='accuracy' " mean?

Comment: It means that you define the score parameter. You can use accuracy, average_precision, roc_auc etc. I edited my answer and I added a helpful link. Also, you can see here [Plotting Learning Curves](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html) another example in which the y axis of the plot says "score". This is what you define when you use scoring="accuracy" or something else.

Comment: @ANKURSATYA no problem. I edited my previous comment as well, adding another link.